# GoTa Series shows NaN, but debugger shows values

Tags: go, gota

I am trying to do some data science magic with golang. To do that I have starting reading in a csv file of names, and the biological gender.
I work with [Gota](https://github.com/go-gota/gota) as Dataframe framework

I started to calculate a hardvowel score for the name of every entry like this:

```
hardVowSeries := df.Select("name").Rapply(hardVowels)
hardVowSeries.SetNames("hard Vowel Score")
```

My hardVowels function looks like this:

```
func hardVowels(s series.Series) series.Series {
name := s.String()
name = prepName(name)

hardVow1 := float32(strings.Count(name, "p"))
hardVow2 := float32(strings.Count(name, "k"))
hardVow3 := float32(strings.Count(name, "f"))
lengthName := float32(len([]rune(name)))

hardVowScore := (hardVow1 + hardVow2 + hardVow3) / lengthName
return series.Floats(hardVowScore)}
```

Now when I change the Series type to int it work but it rounds it to ints and therefor the score is zero everytime I need to save the values as floats, therefore I changed the type of the series as well as all the numeric types to float32.

When I run it in the debugger it shows the float values correctly but when I print the Series after the function with `Rapply` is done it shows that it is all NaN values.
I would be happy for any help. Thank you.